# how to verified the string as correct date format

Tags: python, validation, datetime

can I know the best way for me to verified the string is in the following formate. I am not sure how i should verified the house and (am or pm)

```
datestring = 'Feb 22 2017, 1:27:42pm'
print(datetime.strptime('Feb 22 2017, 1:27:42', '%b %d %Y, %H:%m:%S'))
```

Comment: Use `%p` for am/pm

Comment: Changed tag to just python. Besides print being a function vs a statement, this code is pretty version independent.

Comment: All the cool kids just use `dateutil.parser`

Comment: @wim: Except for the fact that the [`dateutil`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-dateutil/) module doesn't appear to support Python 3...

Comment: @martineau  What are you talking about?  It's had Python 3 support for many years

Comment: @wim: Sorry, I was confusing dateutil's version numbers with Python's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main issue is actually that `%m` should be `%M`. Lowercase `m` is the month, not the minute. `%p` will parse `'am'` and `'pm'`. You may also want to change `%H` to `%I` since the presence of am/pm implies a 12 hour clock rather than 24:

```
datestring = 'Feb 22 2017, 1:27:42pm'
datetime.strptime(datestring, '%b %d %Y, %I:%M:%S%p')
```

Results in a `datetime` object that can be represented as `2017-02-22 13:27:42` with my locale/platform defaults.

Answer (score 0):

Use regex to see if an entry is in your format. It will return either a SRE_Match object or nothing, so call `bool` on the regex to return `True/False`

```
>>> datestring = 'Feb 22 2017, 1:27:42pm'
>>> bool(re.match(r'([A-Z][a-z]{2} \d{2} \d{4}, \d:\d{2}:\d{2}[am,pm])', datestring))
    True
```