# Python datetime.strptime seems to accept input with an invalid length

Tags: python, datetime, python-datetime

I want to be able to enforce very strict validation for `datetime.strptime()` in python

Python `datetime.strptime` seems to be accepting values that are incorrectly formatted instead of raising an Exception (and trying to leniently parse them).

Example:

`print datetime.strptime('201013112', '%Y%m%d%H%M')`

Expected Output:
 `ValueError: ...`

Actual Output:
`2010-01-31 01:02:00`

Is there a way to make the validation extremely strict(I want the length to match YYYYMMDDHHMM format in this specific example) (Or maybe a library alternative).
I cannot add a length check myself because the format is not fixed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to verified the string as correct date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42400170/how-to-verified-the-string-as-correct-date-format)

Comment: @stovfl, I don't think this is a dup. Clearly the number of characters in the format do not align with the string. The issue is `datetime.datetime` has specific logic or is more lenient.

Comment: It's how `datetime` works. Read the the last Answer from the dup link how to do exact match.

Comment: @stovfl, Aside from an expensive regex dependency, it's also not scalable, or there's no demonstration of how you can scale this for an arbitrary number of formats. But OP is welcome to accept the dup if it solves their problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data is messy. This is a messy solution. First create a dictionary mapping each format code to length, then define a function which tests against expected length before trying to parse as `datetime`:

```
from datetime import datetime

a = '201013112'
form = '%Y%m%d%H%M'

form_lens = {'Y': 4, **dict.fromkeys('mdHM', 2)}

def conv_str(x, form):
    if len(x) != sum(map(form_lens.get, form.replace('%', ''))):
        raise ValueError("Length of input inconsistent with format supplied")
    return datetime.strptime(x, form)

conv_str(a, form)  # ValueError: Length of input inconsistent with format supplied
```

The lengths are derived from [Python's `strftime` directives](http://strftime.org/). You should check your expectations are in line with this reference.